# insert into sql in oracle procedure when alter new columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

table1:

```
create table table1(n number);
```

table2:

```
creaet table table2(n number);
```

procedure:

```
create or replace procedure myPro is
begin
  insert into table1(n) 
    select n from table2;
  commit;
end myPro;
```

now

```
alter table table1 add newclounm number;
alter table table2 add newclounm number;
```

How refactoring my procedure?
I not use `insert into table1 select * from table2;`

I try table1%rowtype, but return error;

Comment: Why don't you want to use - insert into table1(select * from table2). Any Reason?

Comment: example:select a,sum(b),c from table group by a,c.When I create other columns,I always alter all sql to select a,sum(b),c, newcolumn1,newcolumn2 from table group by a,c,newcolumn1,newcoulumn2

Comment: I suggest you to go with dynamic SQL then!!! Build the statement dynamically and execute the statement. I can help you with a sample procedure if needed

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this piece of code

```
    create or replace procedure table_test as
  type v_table1_type is table of table1%rowtype;
  v_tab1_list v_table1_type;
  v_sql       varchar2(4000);
  v_order_sql varchar2(2000);
  v_order     varchar2(2000);
begin
  v_order_sql := 'SELECT listagg(column_name,'','') within group  (order by column_id)
      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''TABLE2''
      group by table_name';

  dbms_output.put_line(v_order_sql);
  execute immediate v_order_sql
    into v_order;

  v_sql := 'select *  from table2 order by ' || v_order;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql bulk collect
    into v_tab1_list;

  forall x in v_tab1_list.first .. v_tab1_list.last
    insert into table1 values v_tab1_list (x);
  commit;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
```

you need to use limit clause if your data volume is high...

Comment: zhanzezhu  means to say that columns should be included dynamically in group by also

Answer (score 0):

> Off the top of my head i can think it can be easily done by the help
>   of dynamic SQL by using ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table.But this design is not at 
>   all recommended. I am assuming that the
>   column names in both the tables are same. Hope below snippet helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myPro
    IS
      lv_cols LONG;
    BEGIN
      SELECT WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
      INTO lv_cols
      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
      WHERE OWNER    = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1'
      GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE1('||lv_cols||')'|| 'SELECT '||lv_cols||' FROM TABLE2';
      COMMIT;
    END ;
```